# Streaming computations on Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I'm trying to use Tensorflow to run a computation over a large-ish (~100GB) amount of video data. The computation graph would be a simple pipeline with two parts, one that runs on CPU and one that runs on GPU. The pipeline operates on individual frames, and I don't need to do any training.

So assuming some other threads are in charge of loading frames into a FIFOQueue `queue_in` and unloading them from `queue_out`, the code would look like this:

```
frame = queue_in.dequeue()
output = queue_out.enqueue(gpu_op(cpu_op(frame)))

with tf.Session():
    output.run()
```

My question is the following: is there any way I can run this pipeline so that *the GPU op and the CPU op are run concurrently on two consecutive frames*?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using `tf.data` for the job. The following [performance guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/performance/datasets_performance) discusses how you can achieve the pipelining you are interested in.